# Excel unexpected open another linked Excel from a Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I created a Access query to select data from a linked Excel file(TableA) like below,

```
accQuery:

SELECT C.item1, C.item2 
FROM (SELECT A.A1 AS item1, B.B1 AS item2 FROM TableA AS A LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON A.check = B.check) AS C 
WHERE C.item1 = 'C'
```

Then in another Excel file, I set this query in a Worksheet to get the query result from the linked table, and call the `RefreshAll` function in the `Workbook_Open()` event.

Finally, I use a command line program to open the Excel, wait for the query done(via `CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` function), then save and close. Yesterday, the all procedure works well; but today when I execute the program again and it just hang at there without error due to the **TableA** Excel file has been unexpected opened.

Do anyone know how to avoid opening the non-target Excel file in a SQL query?
(if I refresh the query in the command line program, the symptom will not occur; but I just want to know if there has another method to avoid this)

Comment: Hi - I'm not clear why you are mentioning Access when you are talking about getting data from one Excel workbook to another. Do you mean Power Query?

Comment: Nope, I set a query in Access and then link it into the Excel file; but the Excel need to refresh the linked query to get the newest data, so I put the `refreshAll` function in Excel `Workbook_Open()` event. Even I just use this two files, when event is invoked, the Excel will open another Excel file which is list in the query of Access.

Comment: Sorry - I'll clarify my question: given that you can get data from one Excel workbook into another quite easily (and without opening the 1st workbook) just using Excel functionality, why are you using Access? If this is part of some bigger process that you haven't described, then we probably need to know what the whole process is in order to hopefully provide a solution that will work

Comment: Yes, the Access is used as the data center for indirect accessing data, sorry for didn't describe clear. The end Excel will link to the temp result from the Access SQL query, which will use Excel worksheet or Access data table to form the result.
The question is using same Access SQL query, execute it in Excel via calling `refreshAll` function then Excel will open the workbook which is used to form the temp result; but when execute it in Access, the Excel won't be opened.